# Is is ok to unmount and re-mount `<Switch>` and `<Route>` on every route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to show a a spinner between route changes. Something like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-williamson-dvxcj

[image]

So this is what I've come up with:

```
function LayoutLoaderTransition() {
  const [, setForceUpdateBoolean] = useState(false);    // A BOOLEAN STATE TO FORCE RE-RENDERS
  const location = useLocation();                       // WILL RE-RENDER WHEN THE LOCATION CHANGES
  const lastPathname_ref = useRef(null);                // REF TO REMEMBER THE LAST PATHNAME (ROUTE)

  const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => {               // CALLBACK TO FORCE UPDATE THIS COMPONENT
    setForceUpdateBoolean(prevState => !prevState);     // TOGGLE BOOLEAN STATE
  }, []);

  if (lastPathname_ref.current === null) {              // ON FIRST RENDER, LAST PATH REF IS NULL
    lastPathname_ref.current = location.pathname;       // INITIALIZE IT WITH CURRENT RENDER
  }

  useEffect(() => {                                          // EFFECT TO CHECK IF THERE'S A NEW ROUTE
    if (lastPathname_ref.current !== location.pathname) {    // IF NEW ROUTE IS DIFFERENT THAN LAST
      lastPathname_ref.current = location.pathname;          // UPDATE REF
      setTimeout(() => forceUpdate(), 500);                  // FORCE UPDATE AND LAST PAHTNAME WILL BE === NEW
    }
  }, [forceUpdate, location.pathname]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
      {lastPathname_ref.current !== location.pathname ? (    // WHEN NEW PATHNAME !== LAST PATHNAME
        <div>Loading</div>                                   // SHOW LOADING
      ) : (                                                  // OTHERWISE SHOW COMPONENT <Main/>
        <div>
          <Main />
        </div>
      )}
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// <Main/> IS BEING UN-MOUNTED AND RE-MOUNTED BETWEEN ROUTE CHANGES

function Main() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={HOME} component={Home} />
      <Route exact path={ROUTE1} component={Component1} />
      <Route exact path={ROUTE2} component={Component2} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

It works, but I'm finding it a bit weird, **because I'm unmounting and re-mounting the `<Switch>` and all the `<Route>` inside `<Main/>` on every route change.** Usually they only mount once, and only re-render between route changes.

Is this a bad practice? Am I risking losing any "routing information" by remounting them on every route change? Or is it ok?

---

**NOTE1:** The `500ms setTimeout()`  here is just for the demo. In real code I won't need it. The spinner will show, and will be shown on the screen until React finishes rendering the next page. On a slower phone, the spinner will be visible for longer, and vice-versa on a faster phone.

See how it looks without the timeout, and there is a heavy component being rendered on Route2. The user sees the spinner while the heavy route is rendering.

[image]

---

**EXTRA:**

I'm doing this because on mobile devices (lower CPU power) the new routes takes a while to render, and if I don't show a spinner, the UX is terrible. The user clicks on a `<Link/>` and feels like nothing has happened until the new page finished rendering. So I need to show a loader between route changes.

**NOTE:**

There are no API calls being made. The data is already fully present when the App loads for the 1st time. If there were API calls, I could be handling the `loading` state inside each component, instead of doing on a higher level, like I'm doing here.

Comment: I suppose you must figure out why your pages are taking time to load instead of adding this hack since making the user wait 500ms for each interaction may feel weird. Also what if the data didn't even load in 500ms you might still see a blank page

Comment: Did you try to use `Suspense` on your main router?

Comment: Thanks. I've though about that, on Desktop I have no issues. It's real-time and I don't even need a loader. But rendering dozens of SVG images and charts takes a while on mobile devices. So I need the spinner between route changes. The 500ms on the code was just for the demo. In my real case I don't need a timeout, because the spinner will show, and will remain on the screen while the next page is being rendered. The faster your phone, less time you will see the spinner. Slow phone, the spinner will be visible for longer.

Comment: @SMAKSS Suspense is for data fetching, isn't it? My issue is with sync code. Could I use suspense for that? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, as far as I know, if you wrap your whole `switch` within a `Suspense` with `fallback` it will execute on each route change.

Comment: Regardless of the "hack". Is it ok to re-mount the `<Switch>` and `<Route>` on every route change? Or is it bad for some reason?